# No Handler found error while implementing the spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I have been trying to run this example project from the web to learn spring mvc but facing the below issue:

```
Mar 03, 2019 8:47:53 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springmvcexample/employee-module] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
```

The URL that I am hitting is:
http://localhost:8080/springmvcexample/employee-module

Below are the related files:

EmployeeController class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employee-module")
public class EmployeeController 
{
    @Autowired
    EmployeeManager manager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllEmployees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAllEmployees(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("employees", manager.getAllEmployees());
        return "employeesListDisplay";
    }
}
```

Web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Hello World Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.howtodoinjava.demo.*" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Can someone please help on the same.

Below is the screenshot of the servers view of the app deployed
[image]

Comment: Why not `http://localhost:8080/springmvcexample/employee-module/getAllEmployees`?

Comment: Still getting the same issue

Comment: @ghostrider as I said, post the dialog screenshot with the deployed artifact, via the Server view.

Comment: @LppEdd posted the screenshot

Comment: @ghostrider you targeted "/springmvcexample/employee-module", but you need to call "/springmvcexample/employee-module/getAllEmployees"

Comment: did that https://imgur.com/a/RoLn5xL

Comment: `com.howtodoinjava.demo.*` is not a valid package name. `base-package` expects a package name. Is your controller under this package, BTW?

Comment: @JBNizet good catch!

Comment: @JBNizet here is the package structure https://imgur.com/a/feo2OMF  I updated the base package to "com.howtodoinjava.demo.controller" still the same issue

Comment: Try by changing the url-pattern to /* in  servlet-mapping *<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>*